# change js confirm to a twitter bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, confirm

I have some JavaScript that displays a confirm dialog box to the user to confirm their action with passed in variables.

However, I must change the plain confirm dialog to a twitter-bootstrap modal.

I have tried several times, read a lot of SO posts and read the twitter bootstrap docs, but I cannot get it to work as my knowledge of js is not good enough. I am getting stuck on the display of the variables in the twitter bootstrap modal.

I am hoping that some one can help me out by giving me some pointers.

Here is my current js dialog code:

```
    function checkboxUpdated(checkbox, count, label, id) {

        if (checkbox.checked) {

            $('#menu_entry_' + id).show();

        } else {

            if (count > 0) {

                if (! confirm('{% trans "You have '+ count +' saved '+ label +'.\n\nIf you leave this option un-checked your saved '+ label +' will be deleted only after you update this page.\n\nAre you sure you want to delete your ' + count + ' saved ' + label +'?" %}')) {

                    checkbox.checked = true;
                    return;

                }

            }

            $('#menu_entry_' + id).hide();

        }

    }
```

**EDIT: ADDED CODE OF #menu_entry_ as requested in comment:**

```
{% for id, menu_entry, selected, item_count in menu_entries %}

    <li id="menu_entry_{{ id }}" {% if not selected %}style="display:none;"{% endif %}>

        <a 

            {% if id == 4 %}

                href="{% url summary_details %}"

            {% elif id == 8 %}

                href="{% url objective_details %}"

            {% elif id == 12 %}

                href="{% url leading_employment_details %}"

            {% elif id == 16 %}

                href="{% url desired_occupation_details %}"

            ....

            {% elif id == 112 %}

                href="/"

            {% else %}

            href="/"

            {% endif %}

            onclick="showProgressAnimation();">
```

**Note that I need to transform the following js confirm code to twitter bootstrap modal code:**

```
if (! confirm('{% trans "You have '+ count +' saved '+ label +'.\n\nIf you leave this option un-checked your saved '+ label +' will be deleted only after you update this page.\n\nAre you sure you want to delete your ' + count + ' saved ' + label +'?" %}')) {
```

Comment: Gonna need to see the HTML for `#menu_entry_*`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your own jQuery plugin. First, add the Bootsrap's modal component to your document.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="confirm-label" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="confirm-label"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p class="message"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dismiss" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary confirm" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically, the plugin should display the modal when invoked and trigger a `confirm` event if the confirmation button is pressed or `dismiss` otherwise.

```
$.fn.confirm = function (options) {
  var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.confirm.defaults, options);

  return this.each(function () {
    var element = this;

    $('.modal-title', this).html(settings.title);
    $('.message', this).html(settings.message);
    $('.confirm', this).html(settings.confirm);
    $('.dismiss', this).html(settings.dismiss);

    $(this).on('click', '.confirm', function (event) {
      $(element).data('confirm', true);
    });

    $(this).on('hide.bs.modal', function (event) {
      if ($(this).data('confirm')) {
        $(this).trigger('confirm', event);
        $(this).removeData('confirm');
      } else {
        $(this).trigger('dismiss', event);
      }

      $(this).off('confirm dismiss');
    });

    $(this).modal('show');
  });
};
```

An improvement we can make to the code above is to expose the default plugin settings.

```
$.fn.confirm.defaults = {
  title: 'Modal title',
  message: 'One fine body&hellip;',
  confirm: 'OK',
  dismiss: 'Cancel'
};
```

Usage example:

```
$('#confirm').confirm().on({
  confirm: function () {
    console.log('confirm');
  },
  dismiss: function () {
    console.log('dismiss');
  }
});
```

See live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/cdog/4q9t9pk5/.

If you don't want to write your own solution you can try existing projects like: https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog. It looks like what you were looking for. Docs and demos available here: http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/.

Answer (score 2):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/kc79zjtx/)

You want to change your function as shown below. Then there's modal markup to add to the page (see demo) and the event listeners shown below:

```
function checkboxUpdated(checkbox, count, label, id) {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
        $('#menu_entry_' + id).show();
    } else {
        if (count > 0) {
            //save data to use later
            $('#message_p').text( '<the-message-to-show-on-the-modal>' )
            .data('elem', '#menu_entry_' + id)
            .data('chkbox', checkbox);

            //set modal title
            $('#title_h4').text( '<Modal Title>' );

            //show modal
            $('#confirm_modal').modal('show');
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button-yes').on('click',function() {
        var checkbox = $('#message_p').data('chkbox');
        checkbox.checked = true;
        $('#confirm_modal').modal('hide');
    });

    $('#confirm_modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
        var elem = $('#message_p').data('elem');
        $(elem).hide();
    });
});
```

**NOTE:** Let us know if you have any questions.